# Having a few problems with proofs regarding Matrix Multiplication and Markov Chains

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I'm sorry if my formatting is sloppy, this is my first time posting on this forum, and I'm not certain how to use the site's formatting.

I need to prove four things, and I'm running into a few road blocks. Specifically, I need to prove the following:

1. PROVE: If $v$ is a probability vector (all entries add up to $1$), and A is a stochastic matrix (meaning a square matrix where the columns are probability vectors), prove $Av$ is another probability vector.

   - For this one, I was given the hint of using $S= [1, 1, 1, ...]$, and to remember $VS=v_1+v_2+...$
2. SHOW: $v$ is a probability vector if and only if $Sv=1$, and $v(i)≥0$

   - I also need to show that A is stochastic if and only if $SA=S$ and all entries $≥0$.
   - The hint given for this one is that $B[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$ = $[Ba_1, Ba_2, ..., Ba_n]$
3. Let A be stochastic. If $(λ,v)$ is an eigenpair, then either $λ=1$, or the sum of the entries in $v=0$.

   - The hint here is to use $S=[1, 1, ...]$.
4. Let A be a stochastic $2 \times 2$ matrix. Show that $1$ is an eigenvalue of A, and the other eigenvalue satisfies $|λ|≤1$.

   - The thing to remember is that, as a stochastic matrix, the entries are $[a, b, 1-a, 1-b]$.

Any help for any or all of these would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use LateX for mathematical symbols. For starters, just put opening and closed $ sign. Also you need not use different scripts like greek for symbols α, β, δ. LaTeX has them inbuilt :)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to use lowercase $\mathbf{s}$ for the vector $(1,\ldots,1)$. By $\sum_i$, I mean $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$, where $n$ is the dimension of your objects.

2. To prove an equivalence, you need to prove two implications. The assumption that all entries $\geq 0$ serves to prevent values larger than $1$ cancelling out with negative values smaller than $-1$, other than that, it is not needed in the proof.

$\implies$: we assume that $\mathbf{v}$ is a probability vector, that means $\sum_i \mathbf{v}_i=1$. If we multiply the two vectors, we obtain $\mathbf{sv}=\sum_i \mathbf{s}_i\mathbf{v}_i$. Since $\forall i$ $\mathbf{s}_i=1$, we can further simplify $\sum_i \mathbf{s}_i\mathbf{v}_i=\sum_i \mathbf{v}_i$, which we assumed to be equal to 1.

$\impliedby$: Pretty much read the whole thing backwards. Assume $\mathbf{sv}=1$, then $1=\mathbf{sv}=\sum_i \mathbf{s}_i\mathbf{v}_i=\sum_i \mathbf{v}_i$.

As for the matrix case, use the just proven statement for every column individually, since the columns add up to $1$, just like $\mathbf{v}$.

3. For an eigenpair $(\lambda,\mathbf{v})$, the following holds:
   $$\lambda\mathbf{v}=A\mathbf{v}$$
   Let's multiply the equation by $\mathbf{s}$ from the left and exploit what we proved in 2):
   $$\lambda=\lambda\mathbf{sv}=\mathbf{s\lambda v}=\mathbf{s}A\mathbf{v}\overset{2)}{=}\mathbf{sv}\overset{2)}{=}1$$
   $\lambda = 1$ is clearly a solution, the case $\sum_i\mathbf{v}_i=0$ is in conflict with the definition of a probability vector.
4. You get the eigenvalues as roots of a determinant of the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
   a-\lambda & b \\
   1-a & 1-b-\lambda \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   that is
   $$0\overset{!}{=}(a-\lambda)(1-b-\lambda)-b(1-a)=\lambda^2+(b-a-1)\lambda+(a-b)$$
   Notice that $1$ is a root. Since $$\big{(}\lambda^2+(b-a-1)\lambda+(a-b)\big{)}:\big{(}\lambda-1\big{)}=\lambda + b - a$$ the other eigenvalue is $a-b$, which is always $\in[-1,1]$